# Почему не передаются данные через вебсокеты?

Tags: python, flask, websocket, socket.io

В веб-приложении, написанным с помощью Flask, мне нужно передавать (например, раз в 10 секунд) некие данные, рассчитанные алгоритмом, из сервера клиенту. Раньше для этого я использовал ajax, но решил перейти на вебсокеты. Я решил использовать Flask SocketIO для этого и все настроил, но данные почему-то не передаются, хотя никаких ошибок в консоли не наблюдается.

Вот, что я вижу в консоли программы:

**Sending packet data None**

**Reсeived packet data**

...и так далее

То есть видно, что при отправке ничего не передается, хотя я уверен на 100%, что **func1()** возвращает данные.

Также в консоли браузера я заметил следующие ошибки:

**Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.**

**Unchecked runtime.lastError: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received**

Вот мой серверный код:

```
@socketio.on('connect')
def handle_connect():
    print('Client connected')

@socketio.on('disconnect')
def handle_disconnect():
    print('Client disconnected')

@socketio.on('update_data')
def handle_send_data():
    data = func1()
    emit('update_data', data, broadcast=True)
```

Вот клиентский код:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + '5000');

socket.on('update_data', function(response) {
    var tableRows = "";
    $.each(response, function(index, item) {
        tableRows += "<tr><td>" + item.symbol + "</td><td><img src='" + item.logo + "' alt='Logo'></img>" + item.b + "</td><td>" + item.bb + "</td><td><img src='" + item.bs + "' alt='Logo'></img>" + item.bse + "</td><td>" + item.bso + "</td><td>" + item.pp + "</td></tr>";
    });
    $("#data tbody").html(tableRows);
    $("#loading-message").css("display", "none");
  });
});
```

**Примечание:** когда я вставляю код из функции **handle_send_data** в функцию **handle_connect**, то данные передаются, но потом не обновляются, а просто остаются на странице без обновления.

То есть все же данные могут передаваться, но, наверное, что-то не так с функцией **handle_send_data** раз из нее они не передаются клиенту.

Буду рад любым советам и ответам.